# Remove duplicate objects from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on the chat concept using xmpp framework. But I am getting the issue while showing the chat history. In core data duplicate entries get saved I am unable to find the issue. Then I put the trick while fetching the array from Core Data. I tried to remove duplicate entries before loading the array.

```
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                              cacheName:nil];
NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResult = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

NSSet *uniqueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:mutableFetchResult];
NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[uniqueSet allObjects]];
NSMutableArray *entries = uniqueArray;
```

But it is not giving the correct object of array. There are still duplicate objects. May be I am doing something wrong while removing duplicacy. Please correct me and give some solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define duplicates? Should you avoid saving a duplicate data instead?

Comment: Did you try this? : [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctValues:YES];

Comment: @tyt_g207 let me try with your given code of line

Comment: @Larme I tried to not insert the duplicate values. but did not got the result.

Comment: Update: this setting is only valuable for NSDictionnaryResultType (as described in NSFetcHRequest.h : /* Returns/sets if the fetch request returns only distinct values for the fields specified by propertiesToFetch. This value is only used for NSDictionaryResultType. Defaults to NO. */

Comment: The comment provided by @Larme is right. You should explain what's your concept of duplicate...

Comment: But why you save duplicate to Core Data, you should check For Duplicates before saving - i think you have some ID field, and before saving just fetch Id list and compare with you new data...

Comment: @tyt_g207  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest                                                                managedObjectContext:moc                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
cacheName:nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResult = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

Comment: @mvadim I tried with this   if ((!([onlybodyarray containsObject:message.body]&&[fromarray containsObject:message.fromStr]))&&(!([onlybodyarray containsObject:message.body]&&[toarray containsObject:message.toStr]))) {
                BOOL isSaveSuccess = [[self managedObjectContext_message] save:&error];
                
                if (!isSaveSuccess) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to save chat history: %@,%@",error,[error userInfo]);
                }else {
                    NSLog(@"Saved Successfully");} but no rsult. it is still inserting duplicate entries.

Comment: and the better way is to prevent duplicates :) Take a look at how have you created duplicates.

Comment: @mvadim I am not getting you.

Comment: Try to put breakpoint to "if" and check step by step...

Comment: Maybe your arrays do not contain all DB objects. So it was return NO when you did your check (containsObject:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a category for your Core Data entity that gets duplicate copies and write something like

```
+ (Item *)itemWithParsedDictionary:(NSDictionary *)parsedItem inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Item *item;
    if (parsedItem) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", parsedItem[@"Name"]];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (!matches || [matches count] > 1) {
            NSLog(@"Multiple copies of unique item detected in the document");
        } else if (![matches count]){
            item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context];

            item.name = parsedItem[@"Name"];
        } else {
            item = [matches lastObject];
        }
    }
return item;
}
```

There is an excellent lesson in the excellent course about that:
[Stanford University free course CS193p](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550)

Comment: I would suggest replacing the executeFetchRequest:error: with countForFetchRequest:error: since the latter will be a lot less expensive than doing a full fetch.

Comment: @nemesys well then how would you handle  `item = [matches lastObject];` then?